# tvOS - How to segue back to root controller without seeing intermediate views

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboard, tvos, unwind-segue

I am making a simple game. The storyboard flow looks like:

```
[Title Screen] --> [Game Screen] --> [Game Over Screen]
```

From the Game Over screen, I'd like to jump back to the title screen directly, without seeing the Game Screen appear, when the user presses MENU.

I first attempted this in my `GameOverViewController`:

```
- (void) pressesBegan:(NSSet<UIPress*>*) presses withEvent:(UIPressesEvent*) event
{
    for (UIPress* press in presses)
    {
        if (press.type == UIPressTypeMenu)
        {
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            return;
        }
    }

    [super pressesBegan:presses withEvent:event];
}
```

It pops correctly, but the animation is not disabled. You can clearly see the game screen appear for a second, with a very visible fade in/out transition. The game view even gets `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewWillDisappear:` messages.

So next, I tried replacing the `pop` an unwind segue.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Game Over to Title" sender:self];
```

This effect looks slightly different—the game screen only appears for an extremely brief duration for some reason—but it is visible for at least 1 or 2 frames before we get back to the title. I've disabled the "Animates" checkbox on the unwind segue in Xcode.

How should I go about this? I'm about ready to just dump storyboards entirely and try doing it another way. I feel like they're more complicated than managing the nibs myself. If I can't get the segues to go cleanly, the only other alternative I can think of is to introduce a dummy black screen into the hierarchy and figure out how to transition via a pop and a segue:

```
                          [Game Screen]
                           /
[Title Screen] --> [Dummy Black Screen]
                           \
                          [Game Over Screen]
```

Answer (score 1):

Include all your "poppable" navigation in a new navigation controller, and pop the navigation controller itself whenever you need. I think it has to be modally presented but I'm unsure about that part. Give it a try in both cases, it's pretty much a one-liner.

Or (this isn't clean) you could first pop the parent controller without animation, that would be invisible to the user, and then `popToRoot` just like you did. With the intermediate view already popped, you'd be good, its just not really re-usable anywhere else and is bad practice.

Comment: I'll try the first suggestion--could you please explain how to do that? I haven't ever seen that technique before.

Comment: I've never programmed for tvOS but i'm guessing it's the same as iOS. You just put all your controllers (in storyboard) into a navigation controller's hiearchy, and at some point when you want it,  you `this.navigationcontroller.pop`